# jQuery slideshow loop fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow

I've been trying to implement snook.ca's Simplest jQuery Slideshow, but when applied to child elements inside a `<ul>` instead of a straightforward stack of images. I've successfully got the slideshow rotating through the necessary child elements, but I've run out of know-how when ending the sequence and returning to the beginning.

*I'd like the sequence to return to the first `<p>` child element and continue in an endless loop.*

You can see a demo of the slideshow in operation on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/uyegi3/). Apologies for the verbosity of the jQuery code; I'm sure it could be optimized.

For posterity here is the HTML:

```
<header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="current">
          <h3>...</h3>
          <p><img src="#"><span>...<a href="#">...</a></span></p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h3>...</h3>
          <p><img src="#"><span>...<a href="#">...</a></span></p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h3>...</h3>
          <p><img src="#"><span>...<a href="#">...</a></span></p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h3>...</h3>
          <p><img src="#"><span>...<a href="#">...</a></span></p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

And here is the jQuery:

```
$('header nav li').not('.current').children('p').hide();
   setInterval(function(){
     $('header nav li.current').children('p').hide()
     .parent('li').removeClass()
     .next('li').addClass('current')
     .children('p').show()
     .end();
   },3000);
```

Any help you could give would be much appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just break your chaining after selecting the next `li`. If there is no next `li`, the `length` of the result set will be `0`. When that happens, loop back to the beginning. Then, just finish your setup. Here is a revision on your JSBin code that [shows it working](http://jsbin.com/uyegi3/2):

```
$('header nav li').not('.current').children('p').hide();
setInterval(function(){
  var $next = $('header nav li.current').children('p').hide()
  .parent('li').removeClass()
  .next('li');

  if(!$next.length) $next = $('header nav li:first');

  $next.addClass('current')
  .children('p').show();
},3000);
```

Comment: Happy to help man! Great question, and having the JSBin link was fantastic.