# Looping jquery slideshow

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow

I know how to make a slideshow though I don't know how to make it run on a continuously instead of just once over I have not made the slideshow yet so will not be able to show you any code but I do know that I will be using a `<ul>` inside a div with `overflow: hidden;` then using position absolute on the li items so that they are stacked on top of each other

I though of using jquery when the opacity of an item changes then if the opacity is 0 then redo the loop like that. How would that be coded

I would much prefer not having to fall back on plugins that other people have made

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may want to use existing jQuery plugins, or at least look at how they work.

Comment: I prefer not to use plugins

Comment: If you look at plugins the majority of them are moving images horizontally. When you are on the last image set the position of the first image. If you don't try to write code it is not difficult to help you and you don't try by yourself.

Comment: I can easily make a slideshow that does that though it doesn't loop is what I am saying

Answer (score 0):

Since you know how to make a slideshow, I'll just give you some code for the looping part:

```
var images = new Array("image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", etc.)
var index = 0;

// Visually clearer method (my opinion)
function changeImage() {
    index++;
    if (index == images.length) index = 0; // Avoid going out of range

    $("#imageElement").attr("src", images[index]);
}

setInterval("changeImage()", 5000);

// More concise method
setInterval(function() {
    index++;
    if (index == images.length) index = 0;
    $("#imageElement").attr("src", images[index]);
}, 5000);
```

If you want captions I'd recommend an array "parallel" to the image source array.

Comment: Hmm... there must be a simpler way of doing it because I have seen it done but I can't seem to find where

Comment: I know how to create the slideshow I just need to know how to make the images loop

Comment: This is a way to do that! Store the image paths in an array and you're pretty much done.

Comment: Is there a simpler way to do it cos I want the images to be set in the html

Comment: Search for [jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16884218/jquery-slideshow-not-looping-correctly?rq=1) [slideshows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736803/why-is-my-jquery-cycle-slideshow-not-working?rq=1) [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972587/jquery-slideshow-continuous-loop?rq=1) to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293919/jquery-slideshow-loop-fail?rq=1). There are plenty of ways to do it with the images set in the HTML. Try `var images = $("#slideshow img")`, and you treat `images` as an array.

Comment: I'm sorry for going on about it but can you please tell me is there a way to launch a function when the opacity of an element is changed

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. The function should launch, regardless of any element's opacity.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do with opacity.
You are right Ollie.You have to go with similar html structure that you described in your question.Like this :

```
<div class="mask">
   <ul class="images">
     <li style="display: none;">
      <img border="0" usemap="#Map" src="images/image.png">
     </li>
     <li style="display: none;"> 
      <img src="images/image1.png"> 
     </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="pagination">
  <ul class="triggers">
    <li class="">1</li>
    <li class="">2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS for the above structure will be like this:

```
.mask {
    float: left;
    height: 156px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 822px;
}
ul.images {
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}
ul.images li {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
ul.triggers {
    left: 870px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    top: 250px;
}
ul.triggers li {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    font: bold 10px arial;
    margin: 0 3px;
    padding: 2px;
}
ul.triggers li.selected {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #000000;
}
```

Some script which makes this work as slide show will be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var triggers = $('ul.triggers li');
var images = $('ul.images li');
var lastElem = triggers.length-1;
var target;
triggers.first().addClass('selected');
images.hide().first().show();
function sliderResponse(target) {
images.fadeOut(300).eq(target).fadeIn(300);
triggers.removeClass('selected').eq(target).addClass('selected');
}
triggers.click(function() {
if ( !$(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
target = $(this).index();
sliderResponse(target);
resetTiming();
}
});
function sliderTiming() {
target = $('ul.triggers li.selected').index();
if ( target === lastElem ) { target = 0; }
else { target = target+1; }
sliderResponse(target);
}
var timingRun = setInterval(function() { sliderTiming(); },5000);
function resetTiming() {
clearInterval(timingRun);
timingRun = setInterval(function() { sliderTiming(); },5000);
}
});
```

You can increase/decrease the time interval by changing the 5000 to some other value.